# Exporting constants from a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, export, constants

I'm working with VC9 on Windows.

I have a library (lets call it `libfoo`) which is made of the following files ("include guards" and "#include" directives omited for clarity's sake):

```
// foo.hpp

class Foo
{
  public:
    static const std::string SOME_CONST;
};
```

And:

```
// foo.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"

const std::string Foo::SOME_CONST = "hello";
```

`Foo::SOME_CONST` is exported using a `.def` file.

The library compiles fine: a `libfoo.lib` file and a `libfoo.dll` file are generated.

I used this library in a sample program, like:

```
// main.cpp

#include <foo.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::cout << Foo::SOME_CONST << std::endl; // std::bad_alloc here

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A `std::bad_alloc` is thrown whenever I attempt to use `Foo::SOME_CONST`.

This only happens if I link **dynamically** to `libfoo`. Linking **statically** results in a perfectly working program.

What could possibly be going on here ? Is it legal to export a `std::string` constant that way ?

Comment: With 'dynamically' you mean using GetProcAddress() ?

Comment: @ur: No, I mean using `libfoo` as a DLL but still linking to a `libfoo.lib` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if dll actually does dynamic initialization, because it might not, standard has no requirements for dynamic libraries. Wrapping globals in static functions can be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport). Stop worrying about .def files and all of that rubbish- let the compiler do the work.

Comment: I wish I could unfortunatley I cannot... It took me 5 months to convince my collegues to use a version control system. No chance that they drop usage of `.def` files before the next decade.

Comment: I wish that there was a better option, but the reality is that __declspec is far more powerful, reliable, and usable. What I suggest is, use __declspec to solve the sample problem, and then ask your colleagues how to solve it with a .def file, and if it takes them a long time or they can't, then either they should change or you need new colleagues.

Comment: I will give it a try and keep you posted. Thank you.

Comment: def file allows you to specify both undecorated name and ordinal, which can be useful. If it's not, then there is no reason to use one.

Answer (score 1):

Are the library and the main application linking to the same version of the standard library and/or CRT and/or MFC, with exactly the same settings?  I've seen allocation issues when using different versions of the CRT,  and also fought bugs caused by different iterator debugging settings between a library and its including application.

Comment: Yes they are built with the same tools and same options. I rebuilt both the library and the program several times to be really sure they were compiled the same way.